# Moment.js startof() issue

Tags: angular, date, typescript, momentjs

I want get todays starting time and I am using moment.js for this.
I tried this:

```
let startDate = moment().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:SS');
let endDate = moment().endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:SS');
console.log('start date:' + startDate);
console.log('end date:' + endDate);
```

the result is

`start date: 2017-05-15T12:00:00:00
 end date: 2017-05-15T11:59:59:99`

but actually my expected output is

`start date: 2017-05-15T00:00:00:00
 end date: 2017-05-15T23:59:59:99`

starting date Hours should be `00` not `12` and end date hours shouls be `23` not `11`. Can someone please explain me why `startOf('day')` and `endOf('day')` not giving me desired result.

Is there perhaps something I am missing?

Comment: *Is there perhaps something I am missing?* the documentation? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/. startOf is not the issue. The issue is how you're formatting the moment.

Comment: that means I have to change the format from `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:SS` to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SS`

Comment: can you please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue if how you're displaying the moment. Use `HH` instead of `hh`, [as documented](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).